# Cloudant Error: "The `source' property must exist and be either a string or an object."

Tags: pouchdb, cloudant

I am using PouchDB 6.1.1 on the client-side and IBM Cloudant on the server-side. It saves to PouchDB with no issue. When I replicate using myPouch.replicate.to(..), I get 201 the status but the response has forbidden error with message/reason "The `source' property must exist and be either a string or an object." and status 500. What could be the reasons behind getting this error?

This is the doc I put to PouchDB successfully:

```
{
    _id: "Test2017-01-11T13:47:48-05:00",
    completed: false,
    created_by: "Joes Moes",
    created_on: "2017-01-11T13:47:48-05:00",
    durationInSeconds: 1898,
    edited: false,
    guestVisit: false,
    manualVisit: false 
}
```

This is the response object after replicating to the Cloudant.

```
{
    doc_write_failures: 1,
    docs_read: 1,
    docs_written: 0,
    end_time: Wed Jan 11 2017 13:54:38 GMT-0500 (EST),
    errors: [{
        error: "forbidden",
        id: "Test2017-01-11T13:47:48-05:00",
        message: "The `source' property must exist and be either a string or an object.",
        name: "forbidden",
        ok: true,
        reason: "The `source' property must exist and be either a string or an object."
    }],
    rev: "1-fdebae00ecfe324c91e85a88fd823442",
    status: 500,
    last_seq: 25,
    ok: true,
    start_time: Wed Jan 11 2017 13:54:37 GMT-0500 (EST),
    status: "complete"
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is your replication configured, for example is it live? Post your replication code.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the answers! I found the issue on the database.

On the client-side I was using the code below to replicate to cloudant:

```
myPouchDB.put(doc); 
myPouchDB.replicate.to(myCouchDB);
```

The problem was in the database itself. Somehow a replication design document (_design/_replicator) was added to that database which was causing an issue. After deleting that document, the replication from the PouchDB to Cloudant worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my JSON documents to CouchDb the properties are quoted. I notice they are not in your document. Perhaps you could try this:

```
{
    "_id": "Test2017-01-11T13:47:48-05:00",
    "completed": false,
    "created_by": "Joes Moes",
    "created_on": "2017-01-11T13:47:48-05:00",
    "durationInSeconds": 1898,
    "edited": false,
    "guestVisit": false,
    "manualVisit": false 
}
```

instead?